# How do I override a prettierrc.json file?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, prettier

How do I override a .prettierrc.json file in my Prettier settings.json?

There are configs in that .prettierrc.json that I do not want locally and I am not bound by any authority to use them, more of a preference of the individual who added that .prettierrc.json file.

I am trying to find a happy medium where I get to keep my config and everyone else can go with the config in that .prettierrc.json file.

Comment: What sort of project are you working on where linter settings aren't mandatory?

Comment: @NickBailey, I am not sure what you mean, I have worked on tons of projects with various companies where they are not mandatory.

Comment: Huh. I've literally never seen a project where linting wasn't part of the build and/or precommit hooks... I guess that's just different experiences.

Comment: That's a recipe for commits (and maybe PRs) full of unrelated style changes. The point of using tools like Prettier is to standardise so you're _not_ spending all of your time on styling. If you don't like the current settings, then either advocate for changing them or _use them anyway_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, there is a lot of context that would not be appropriate to get into here. I am in complete agreement with you and Nick Bailey. This startup actually advocates for no standardization. I have actually been arguing your position for months now. The thing I was told last was its best to have no linter or Prettier because then everyone will come with their own and it will mess up the commits. Those are not my words sir, that is what I was told by someone who has been promoted unofficially. In fact, I have taken your position so much, that will probably be fired for speaking up.